# Quartic unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and existence of generators of the form $\sqrt[4]{a}$ for an integer $a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, ramification

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$ where $p$ is a prime number such that $p-1$ is divisible by $4$. Furthermore, let $F/K$ be the unramified extension of degree $4$.

> **Question**: Does $F/K$ always have a generator of the form $\sqrt[4]{a}$ (equivalently, $F = K(\sqrt[4]{a})$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$?

I noticed that for $p=5,13$, it is $F = K(\sqrt[4]{2})$. However, this observation is false for $p=17$ since $2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $17$. I am interested in this question because the claim is true if we assume that $F/K$ has degree $2$ instead of $4$ and I would like to know to what extent this can be generalized.

Comment: "$2$ is not a quadratic residue $\bmod 17$".  So $6^2\not\equiv 2$ anymore?  Maybe you mistyped meaning "$2$ _is_ a quadratic residue"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively let $g$ an integer having order $p-1$ modulo $p$.

A root of $x^4-g\bmod p$ will have order $4(p-1)$.

And $4(p-1)$ divides $p^4-1=(p^2+1)(p+1)(p-1)$ but not $p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)$.

Whence $x^4-g\bmod p$ is irreducible ie. $F=\Bbb{Q}_p[x]/(x^4-g)$ is your unramified extension of degree $4$.

Answer (score 4):

There is always such an $a$. The assumption on $p$ guarantees that the base field contains 4th roots of unity. It then follows from Kummer theory that any extension of degree $4$ is generated by taking a 4th root.

Comment: I already understand that there is a primitive 4th root of unity over the base field, and I already understand that Kummer theory gives us a generator which is a 4th root. The more interesting question to me is why I can just take some 4th root of an integer. Could you explain this?

Comment: @Ribbity -- got it! That follows from Krasner's lemma (you agree there's some $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ (a priori $\mathbb{Q}_p$ but you could just multiply by a 4th power of $p$ to clear denominators), and if you pick $a$ sufficiently close to $\alpha$ $p$-adically then the polynomials $x^4 - a$ and $x^4 - \alpha$ generate the same extension.)